# What is this pipe in the attic for?

Tags: pipe, attic, roofing, old-pipes

I see this silver pipe in the attic that doesn't seem to lead anywhere. There is a hole in the wood, maybe it used to go outside? Right now the hole is covered, probably with the roofing.

Just wondering what the pipe might be used for? Or at least where to start looking for its other end?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That is what we use to give cable companies the finger.  Add more pipe though the roof and get a TV antenna.  What room is under that pipe or can you see the bottom of pipe?

Comment: Do you have underground service into your house?  That pipe might be from an old overhead service that came in through the roof.

Comment: Looks like straight threads, and not corroded, so two things that point to it being rigid or intermediate metallic electrical conduit, (RMC or IMC) not "pipe" (yup, looks like pipe, same sizes as pipe, but slightly different in details.)

Comment: I would say a plumbing vent it is more likely to be a vent than conduit.

Comment: Find the other end, it may come handy in the future if you want to add networking etc in the rooms below.